# How to Live Streaming on YouTube?

Tags: streaming

I'm looking for a way to stream to YouTube Live on my computer. I know there are various tools available for Windows, but I haven't found anything for Linux. I prefer not to use G+ Hangouts, but go right to actual streaming. Does anybody know of any tools for Linux that will stream to YouTube Live, or is there a Windows tool that works without any issues under WINE?

Comment: It's possible. Take a twitch streaming guide, and change the twitch urls for the youtube stream url.

Comment: take a look at this: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/09/watch-live-streams-on-ubuntu-via-video-player/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not gonna be easy, but we can do it. We will stream to Twitch.tv, which can stream to YouTube Live.

Here we go:

**Preparing the libraries:** Type these commands in Terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
sudo apt-get install libx264-dev libavcodec-extra-53
```

**The code required to stream:** Open gedit/Text Editor and paste this code: http://shrib.com/ubuntu2twitch

Save the text file as twitch_stream.sh in your /home/ directory.

**Obtaining a Twitch Streaming Key:** Go to http://www.twitch.tv/broadcast/dashboard/streamkey and get your Streaming key. Open gedit/Text Editor and paste the key into it. Name this file as .twitch_key and save it in your /home/ directory, same as the twitch_stream.sh file.

**Going live:** Open Terminal and type this:

```
cd
cd /home/
chmod 755 twitch_stream.sh
```

If there are no errors, you'll see your screen on the Twitch Dashboard.

**Streaming from Twitch to YouTube:** Visit http://www.twitch.tv/settings/connections to setup your YouTube account and got to your live feed to share on YouTube. If Twitch does not allow live streaming to YouTube, why not add a screen to your YouTube feed to ask users to go to Twitch?

Please upvote if you think this helped you.

A big thank you to The Game Engine for the code.

**UPDATE:** Got it!!! There you go: http://sourceforge.net/projects/snowmix/ Install Snowmix first.

And then GStreamer: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/download/ Search on Ubuntu Software Center for the same.

Now read this guide and set it up. Voila, forget Twitch and stream to YouTube directly! http://sourceforge.net/p/snowmix/wiki/Snowmix%20and%20CDNs/

Comment: I'm getting `WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "faac"`. I did `sudo apt-get install faac`, but I got back `faac is already the newest version.`

Comment: Wait, nope, I'm stupid, forgot to install Snowmix. XD I'll get back to you.

Comment: Nope, still having the same problem.

Comment: Try this out: `sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse` . Thisshould install the GStreamer faac plugins and other requirements. Or download GStreamer plugins forUbuntu from Software Center.

Comment: I got `gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse is already the newest version.` in response.

Comment: No, sorry, looks like `gstreamer0.10` isn't installed. That was my bad. I'll try that.

Comment: @Volodya Can you try this?

Comment: I'm still getting `WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "faac"`.

Comment: Try this: `sudo apt-get install faac` to install faac plugins from Ubuntu's repository.

Comment: I still get `faac is already the newest version.`

Comment: What the faac. (Pardon the pun :P). Alright, try this: `sudo apt-get purge faac`, then `sudo apt-get install faac`. This should reinstall a fresh copy of faac if it's defective, though i doubt it. Or try to install this: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-plugins-bad/gst-plugins-bad-1.2.3.tar.xz

Comment: @Sil I say, skip purging the `faac` encoder and try to install the GStreamer Bad Plugins.They're not bad as in defective, but they lack instructions, documents etc. Maybe your faac thingy will get solved.
P.S. Give me some diagnostics output or all the errors you get if possible.

Comment: The GStreamer Bad Plugins are already installed. I don't run into any other problems when I try to run the script. That's all it gives me.

Comment: @Sil Try the GStreamer ugly plugins :p http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-plugins-ugly.html

Comment: Wait wait....try that ugly plugin only if this doesn't work: `sudo apt-get install faac `

Comment: I apologize for my recent inactivity on this thread. I have just recently performed a complete reinstallation of my operating system. In this case, I'm using Kubuntu 14.04. I'l currently redownloading Gstreamer, and I'll get back to you on how this does. Fingers crossed.

Comment: I got Gstreamer installed, but now Snowmix hangs at configuration.

Comment: `ben@ben-Aspire-5250:~/Documents/Snowmix-0.4.3/Snowmix-0.4.3$ ./bootstrap

Found Eurostile font. Good`

It just hangs from there.

Comment: It hangs? :/

Can't do anything about that. Did you talk to Peter Maersk about this? He maintains the SnowMix project.

Comment: do you have an email address for me to reach him at? I couldn't find on on the SourceForge page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [quvi](http://quvi.sourceforge.net/)

From the author's page: quvi project parses stream URLs for Internet applications to access the media of those hosting websites that use the "adobe flash multimedia platform".

First of all, install tool:

```
sudo apt-get install quvi
```

To play the video, you can use your own favorite player: vlc, mplayer ...

Using, for example, mplayer: install, if it is not already installed:

```
sudo apt-get install mplayer
```

`quvi` support a lot of site, including, of course, youtube. for the complete list:

```
quvi --support
```

Now, to watch the video you just have to specifying the program to be executed to play the video and copy the youtube link and pass it as an argument to quvi:

```
 quvi --exec "mplayer %u" "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=youtube_id_video"
```

refer to `man quvi` for more help.

Answer (score -6):

On Linux, there's a variety of apps like [Smplayer](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/), [minitube](http://flavio.tordini.org/minitube) among others but if you just like to download, try [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/), a command line tool for downloading you tube videos. it's written in Python. Hope that helps a little.

Comment: This doesn't seem remotely related to what the user is asking.